# DSE 3.0 Solr : Tomcat giving 404 errors

Tags: tomcat, solr, cassandra, datastax-enterprise

I had Datastax DSE 2.2 with Solr, in which i ran the Wikipedia demo. Everything worked fine. I then upgraded to DSE 3.0, and rebuilt the Solr index. 
Now everytime i hit the URL :

```
http://myserverURL:8983/solr/wiki.solr/admin/
```

I get a 404 'The requested resource (/solr/wiki.solr/admin/) is not available.' from Tomcat.

I looked in /var/log/cassandra/system.log and there is no error.
I found this resource: http://www.datastax.com/docs/datastax_enterprise3.0/upgrade/solr_upgrade
I ran the scripts in there; everything again runs fine for me, but doesnt solve my error.
Any idea ? Have the resource file locations for Tomcat have moved in DSE 3.0 ?

Cheers,
Matt

Comment: try putting this question in http://www.datastax.com/support-forums/forum/datastax-enterprise. Will get a better response

Answer (score 1):

With DSE 3.0 the location of the admin page changed.  It is now found by just going to

```
http://myserverURL:8983/solr/
```

http://www.datastax.com/docs/datastax_enterprise3.0/solutions/dse_search_upload#checking-a-schema